# Exclude Tax set but still including tax

Tags: price, tax, ce-1.9.1.0

Just upgraded to a clean install of 1.9.1.0 from 1.7.0.2. For some reason tax is being subtracted from the unit price so that the total includes tax but is the same as the unit price.

Was there a change between these 2 version that would cause this? I saw something that sounded like a bug fix for this issue in the the base theme for 1.9.1.

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, your beautiful admin screen caught my attention. May I know where to find the admin UI like that?

Comment: @leongelis, I wish I got commission for promoting this extension. I have been telling everyone about it. It is called Wunderadmin and I love it. It had one bug and the developer was very quick to fix it. Liked patched in 1 day and a full release within 8 days. http://bit.ly/1x2dQjM

Comment: Sounds cool. Thanks a million for the sharing, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in an extension called "Subscriptions and Recurring Payments" by "All For Coding". This is a closed source extension and the bug will be fixed by the developer.